# StreamChat - can't show channel member data

Tags: react-native, getstream-io

In my React Native app I'm using the Streamchat RN SDK to implement a chat between `patients` and `doctors`. I created two specific roles for these users and, when rendering the messages list in the `ChannelPreviewMessenger` component, I need to get information from my backend about a specific user (whose role corresponds to `doctor`) by getting its id.

The problem is that the `channel.data.members` object is undefined and I'm not sure whether querying the channel members is a good idea, given that after some requests I receive a 429 Too Many Request HTTP error.

Answer (score 0):

I solved by calling the `async watch()` method and querying the members contained in the object returned from it.